# set schema_search_path does not work with sequencs in h2

Tags: h2

Script

```
drop schema vending if exists  cascade;
drop schema joblog if exists cascade;
drop schema conditions if exists cascade;
create schema if not exists vending;
create schema if not exists joblog;
create schema if not exists conditions;
set schema_search_path vending,joblog,conditions;
set schema joblog;
create sequence job_log_id_seq;
select nextval('JOBLOG.JOB_LOG_ID_SEQ');
select nextval('JOB_LOG_ID_SEQ');
```

only the last statement doesn't work.
Save as h2_bug.sql and run with

```
H2JAR=~/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.199/h2-1.4.199.jar
java -cp $H2JAR org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/tmp/h2_bug -script h2_bug.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

1. All statements from your script work properly in H2 1.4.199.
2. `NEXTVAL` is a legacy compatibility-only function, you shouldn't use it in H2. It actually doesn't use schema search path and the last command works only because the sequence was found in the current schema. The proper method to fetch sequence values in H2 is a standard [`NEXT VALUE FOR [schemaName.]sequenceName`](https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#sequence_value_expression) expression. `VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR JOB_LOG_ID_SEQ;` will check schema search path after the current schema, unlike function that you use.
3. It's rarely appropriate to use the sequence directly, in the most cases identity columns should be used (`ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` or something like it), but you may have own reasons to use the sequence, for example, if you really need to generate the value before row insertion.

Comment: I don't usually use it, but if it is a foreign key to child tables I want the value of the parent table primary key.